# Capifony deploy runs some commands against previous release

Tags: symfony, capifony

I'm running a Capifony deployment.  However, I notice that Capifony's in-built commands are running against the **previous** release, whereas my custom commands are correctly targeting the current release.

For example, if I run `cap -d staging deploy`, I see some commands output like this (linebreaks added):

```
--> Updating Composer.......................................
Preparing to execute command: "sh -c 'cd /home/myproj/releases/20130924144349 &&
php composer.phar self-update'"
Execute ([Yes], No, Abort) ?  |y|
```

You'll see that this is referring to my previous release - from 2013.

I also see commands referring to this new release's folder (from 2014):

```
--> Running migrations......................................
Preparing to execute command: "/home/myproj/releases/20140219150009/
app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction"
Execute ([Yes], No, Abort) ?  |y|
```

In my commands, I use the `#{release_path}` variable, whereas looking at Capifony's code, it's using `#{latest_release}`.  But obviously I can't change Capifony's code.

[This issue against Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/415) talks about something similar, but I don't think it really helps, as again I can't change Capifony's code.

If I delete my `releases` folder on the server, I have a similar problem - `#{latest_release}` doesn't have *any value*, so it attempts to do things like create a folder `/app/cache` (since the code is something like `mkdir -p #{latest_release}/app/cache`).

(Assuming I don't delete the `current` symlink and the `release` folder, the specific error I see is when it fails to copy vendors: `cp: cannot copy a directory, /home/myproj/current/vendor, into itself`.  However, this is just the symptom of the bigger problem - if it thinks the new release is actually the previous one, that explains why `current` also points there!)

Any ideas?  I'm happy to provide extracts from my `deploy.rb` or `staging.rb` (I'm using the multistage extension) but didn't just want to dump in the whole thing, so let me know what you're interested in!  Thanks

Comment: Some additional things that I've tried since: reinstalling capistrano & capifony didn't help, and neither did deploying to an entirely freshly-created hosting account (where I got the `/app/cache` creation-error mentioned above as there were no previous releases).

Comment: Oh, and a fresh copy of the repo on my colleague's machine exhibited the same behaviour :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this one!

I had a step set to run before deployment:

```
before "deploy", "maintenance:enable"
```

This maintenance step (correctly) sets up maintenance mode on the *existing* site (in the example above, my 2013 one).

However, the maintenance task was referring to the previous release by using the `latest_release` variable.  Since the step was running before deployment, `latest_release` did indeed refer to the 2013 release.  However, once `latest_release` has been used, its value is set for the rest of the deployment run - so it remained set to the 2013 release!

I therefore resolved this by changing the maintenance code so that it didn't use the `latest_release` variable.  I used `current_release` instead (which doesn't seem to have this side-effect).  However, another approach would be to define your own variable which gets its value in the same way as `latest_release` would:

```
set :prev_release, exists?(:deploy_timestamped) ? release_path : current_release
```

I worked out how `latest_release` was being set by looking in the Capistrano code.  In my environment, I could find this by doing `bundle show capistrano` (since it was installed with bundler), but the approach will differ for other setups.

Although the reason for my problem was quite specific, my approach may help others:  I created an entirely vanilla deployment following the [Capifony instructions](http://capifony.org/) and gradually added in features from my old deployment until it broke!